# Redirect a blog on blogspot.com to another domain

Tags: redirect, blogspot

Is there a way to redirect an entire blog or a single blog post from blogspot.com (blogger.com) to another domain?

It will be also helpful to make a redirection from one blogspot post to another post within the same blog.

I have tried meta and javascript redirect, but blogspot wont allow both tags.

Answer (score 0):

you can redirect your **xyz.blogspot.com** to **www.xyz.com**. Go to your blog Dashboard-> settings->publishing->give your domain name and click save. Whenever you type **xyz.blogspot.com** it will redirect to **xyz.com**. You can revert these changes any time without altering your posts.

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect your blogspot domain blog to any domain by changing its DNS and Nameserver by logged into domain name control pannel.First go to blogger.com --> settings --> Basic ---> Publishing--> **+** Set up a third-party URL for your blog - Point your own registered URL to your blog. --> now click on + sign and add your domain name including www. formats.
now change DNS and name server as per blogger instructions.

After completeing all steps,do not forget to redirect your naked domain to www.---yourdomain--.com
like xyz.com to www.xyz.com